# Is here any function to show "child" data in table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im making new test application and I have code which is getting data from one table. But I want to select all child data and put them in second table.

So, need a help how to inside of this code, make to select child's data

```
getvehicles() {
    let vehicles = [];
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`vehicles/`)
      .once('value', snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(snap => {
          vehicles.push(snap.val());
        });
        this.setState({
          vehicles
        });
      });

}
```

[image: Firebase Database]

Asked to rewrite...Already got answer and that helps. My question was, selecting data from firebase database, and render in react-table. And from picture you can see database and bellow there is answer how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to loop over the child nodes of the child nodes. If so, you can just nest `forEach()` calls, until you reach the level you want.

So with your current data structure:

```
firebase
  .database()
  .ref(`vehicles/`)
  .once('value', snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(level1 => {
      console.log(level1.key); // 110          
      level1.forEach(level2 => {
        console.log(level2.key); // 098307, 259566, ...          
        console.log(level2.child('pictures').val());
          level2.forEach(level3 => {
            console.log(level3.key);
            console.log(level3.val());
          });
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: yes u save my day....